# C# |= and &= operators

Tags: c#, oop

In an example I saw these operators (|= and &=) but it wasn't explained.
I was looking on Google about it, but I found only results related to the "classic" = operator. 
So I would like to know what are these operators doing. Can somebody explain it to me ?

Comment: [`|=` Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw.aspx)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are simply shorthand assignments like `+=`.  The following are equivalent:

```
s |= t;
s = s | t;
```

And these are also equivalent.

```
s &= t;
s = s & t;
```

For more information on those operators, you can see the MSDN Docs on [`|`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx.aspx) and [`&`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c) Operator.

Comment: Wow ! That was fast ! Thank you for the explain and the links ;-) Sorry for this noob question.

Comment: They aren't strictly equivalent.  The `|=` operator will ensure that the left hand side is only evaluated once, not twice.  It's still an appropriate way to conceptualize it, even though they're not exactly the same.

Comment: @Servy: Thanks for pointing that out.  Aren't they still functionally equivalent, even if the underlying OP-codes might translate slightly differently?

Comment: @mellamokb No, they're not.  In your example `s` might not just be a local variable.  It could be an expression that results in side effects.  The `|=` case those side effects only occur once, in the following example they would occur twice.

Comment: @Servy: Gotcha.  Though that's true with a lot of operations if you don't use good programming practices.  I would consider side effects resulting from modifying a local variable/property a red flag.

Answer (score 1):

[`|=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h5f1zzaw%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`&=`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e669ax02%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) are assignment operators related to the [`|` (bitwise or)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kxszd0kx%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and [`&` (bitwise and)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbf85k1c%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) operators.

Answer (score 1):

They perform bitwise-OR `|=` operations and bitwise-AND `&=` operations with the result being stored in the `lValue`. They're the same as `|` and `&`, but store the result in the `lValue` analogous to the difference between `+` and `+=` or `-` and `-=`.

Answer (score 0):

well `&=` is the same like `i+=`, in other words

`x&=2` is a short form of  `x=x & 2`